# How can you find means by date but keep the length of the data frame?

Tags: r

I am looking to make this table below. I have the first 2 columns of data for 2 years and wanting to calculate the daily mean price and apply it to all relevant days.

| Publish_Date | Product_Price | Daily_Mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-07-01-- | 146---------- | 142------- |
| 2019-07-01-- | 144---------- | 142------- |
| 2019-07-01-- | 136---------- | 142------- |
| 2019-07-02-- | 120---------- | 123------- |
| 2019-07-02-- | 126---------- | 123------- |
| 2019-07-02-- | 123---------- | 123------- |
| 2019-07-03-- | 112---------- | 112------- |

I have tried the following:

```
TGPDailyMean = aggregate(Product_Price ~ Publish_Date, TGP, mean)
```

but it only gives one value per day, shortening the amount of rows by a factor of 3 or so. I need the amount of rows to be the same so I can take the difference between another dataframe and Daily_Mean.

I have also tried:

```
TGP$DailyMean = lapply(TGP$Product_Price, mean)
```

but this only replicates the values in Product_Price and does not find the mean per day.

Comment: Please provide data sample using `dput`

Comment: See `?ave`. For instance `ave(TGP$Product_Price, TGP$Publish_Date, FUN = mean)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tidyverse Solution

You can use `group_by` and `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
TPG %>%
  group_by(Publish_Date) %>%
  mutate(Daily_Mean = mean(Product_Price)) %>%
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   Publish_Date Product_Price Daily_Mean
#>   <chr>                <int>      <dbl>
#> 1 2019-07-01             146        142
#> 2 2019-07-01             144        142
#> 3 2019-07-01             136        142
#> 4 2019-07-02             120        123
#> 5 2019-07-02             126        123
#> 6 2019-07-02             123        123
#> 7 2019-07-03             112        112
```

---

### Base R solution

As suggest by @nicola in the comments, you can also use `ave`:

```
TPG$Daily_Mean <- ave(TPG$Product_Price, TPG$Publish_Date)
TPG
#>   Publish_Date Product_Price Daily_Mean
#> 1   2019-07-01           146        142
#> 2   2019-07-01           144        142
#> 3   2019-07-01           136        142
#> 4   2019-07-02           120        123
#> 5   2019-07-02           126        123
#> 6   2019-07-02           123        123
#> 7   2019-07-03           112        112
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` oneliner

```
library(data.table)
# or setDT(mydata)
setDT(mydata)[, Daily_Mean2 := mean(Product_Price), by = .(Publish_Date)]
#    Publish_Date Product_Price Daily_Mean Daily_Mean2
# 1:   2019-07-01           146        142         142
# 2:   2019-07-01           144        142         142
# 3:   2019-07-01           136        142         142
# 4:   2019-07-02           120        123         123
# 5:   2019-07-02           126        123         123
# 6:   2019-07-02           123        123         123
# 7:   2019-07-03           112        112         112
```